# Suppose a bookshelf contains five discrete math texts, two data structures texts, six calculus texts, and three Java texts

Tags: combinatorics

> (a) How many ways can you choose one of the texts?
>
> (b) How many ways can you choose one of each type of text?

Solution:

a) By the rule of sum, there are all together
$5 + 2 + 6 + 3 = 16$
possibilities to choose one book.

b) By the rule of product, there are all together
$5\cdot 2\cdot 6\cdot 3 = 180$ possibilities to
choose one book from each topic.

Doubt: Why we choose the sum rule for a) and product rule for b)?

Comment: While your answers to both problems are correct, you did not really use the Addition Principle (Rule of Sum) in the first problem.  The Addition Principle applies when you have mutually exclusive events such as a woman choosing to wear a dress or wear a blouse with a skirt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum rule is used when we consider all possible cases. So actually in your calculation you sum the possibilities when you choose book from the first type (5 options), book from the second type (2 options)... In other wors you want to choose one book out of 16 books, so there are 16 possibilities.

On the other hand we use product rule for not related events. And of course the event of picking a book from the first set is independent from the event of pickin a book from the second set of books.